# Flutter - App Linking not working for Android

Tags: android-app-links

I followed the instructions for App Linking here:
[Android App Linking](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links)

When I type the link on my device's browser (Google Chrome), it wont open the app. But when I click the link from (Gchat, Gmail, Discord, Twitter, etc), it opens the installed app. When I click the link from Messenger, it opens the built in web browser, but there is an option to "Open ".

Did I miss something? Already added assetlinks.json in my domain.

I expect that the app will open if I click the link from Messenger or type in Google Chrome.